# How can I find out what URL my game is executing from in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to upload my game to Kongregate and other sites, but on Kongregate I want to invoke one function and other sites I want run another function. How to check in AS3 where (I want to get host like: www.kongregate.com or www.games.com etc) my game is? Or maybe you know other, better way to make this?

Answer (score 4):

I found a post on how to site-lock flash movies/games [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=170251). It is the fourth post down. You can modify it slightly to make it do something or set any variables you need changed.

Here is the code from the post.

```
//Assuming you have a movieclip or sprite named myMovieClip (you can use any movieclip or sprite)
var URLofSWF:String = myMovieClip.loaderInfo.loaderURL;

//You will do some string methods to get domain name etc etc, it's up to you
var domain_parts:Array = _url.split("://");
var domain_parts_2:Array = domain_parts[1].split("/");
var domainOfURL:String = real_domain[0];

 //Then you compare the URL to any URL you wish to allow or disallow
if(URLofSWF == "http://www.google.com/mySwf.swf"){ // strict swf url checking
proceed();
}else{
stopEverything(); // Or inject some funny code to the stealer :P
}
// or 
if(domainOfURL == "www.mysite.com"){ // domain checking only
    proceed();
}else{
    stopEverything(); // Or inject some funny code to the stealer :P
}
```